# How to reference other helper functions in a lightning:datatable dynamic row-level actions function?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

From the [ligtning:datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm) documentation, a helper function can be called from the controller that adds the relevant row-level actions. Copied here...

Controller:

```
 init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
     var actions = helper.getRowActions.bind(this, cmp);
     cmp.set('v.mycolumns', [
         // Other column data here
         { label: 'State', fieldName: 'active', type: 'text' },
         { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions } }
     ]);
     // Fetch or set your data
 },
```

Helper:

```
getRowActions: function (cmp, row, doneCallback) {
    var actions = [];
    if (row['isActive']) {
        actions.push({
            'label': 'Deactivate',
            'iconName': 'utility:block_visitor',
            'name': 'deactivate'
        });
    } else {
        actions.push({
            'label': 'Activate',
            'iconName': 'utility:adduser',
            'name': 'activate'
        });
    }
    // simulate a trip to the server
    setTimeout($A.getCallback(function () {
        doneCallback(actions);
    }), 200);
},
```

I'd like ***to reference some other helper functions*** from within the `getRowActions` helper function but the example doesn't pass the helper in and also `this` that would normally resolve to the helper is undefined.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a reference to the helper. Despite what the documentation says, I'd prefer to bind to the helper, since the controller doesn't have a "this", which is done to prevent accidentally storing data on the component.

```
var actions = helper.getRowActions.bind(helper, cmp);
```

This will set `this` to the helper, and you can then call other methods normally using `this`.